# How can I know a user is downloading a file from their Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a Chrome extension which can forward the download links to my server.

I have two questions:

1. How can I know if a user is downloading a file from Chrome?
2. Is there anyway can let Chrome popup my Chrome extension instead of its default download bar?

Comment: You might want to accept answers to some of your past questions if you want help.

Answer (score 4):

Both things are (currently) impossible to implement because there is no "download" module for Google Chrome extensions.

See the [*Downloads Extensions API Proposal*](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12rNimeeGaA8jEV60PPKtT4pmJYmY9ae_edl3hJyoXYE/edit?hl=en_US); such a feature may be implemented in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my question is how my extension can know a user clicks a download link from the Chrome. The extension does not need to download it. It just forwards the link to my server.

Comment: @swandive: That seems indeed to be what I'm talking about - there is currently no way to intercept or modify download actions/clicks/UI because of a missing API.

Comment: But I know some extensions can do it. ex: Thunder https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmpllenfapkfpdkahamlbmbichihpmmg

Comment: @swandive: I haven't got that extension installed, but looking at the description it redirects to the actual file instead of a download page. That's a matter of parsing a page to look for the download link. I'm still convinced that question #2 is impossible, but perhaps someone else knows how.

Comment: Sorry, gave u the false link. Just tried Thunder on my mac, it works. 
Here is the link of extension:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kflidheceoijjagcaabllfejhgohkcjh

Answer (score 0):

You can detect browser with javascript.

Browser Codename:    `navigator.appCodeName`

Browser Name: `navigator.appName`

Browser Version: `navigator.appVersion`

Platform: `navigator.platform`

User-agent header: `navigator.userAgent`

You can try these functions at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FGqUU/)

**Edit: Misunderstanding...**